# Get distinct values based on two nodes neo4j

Tags: neo4j, distinct, cypher

There are many 'User' nodes any user can send money to other user.

```
(:User)-[r:SENT_MONEY]->(:User)
```

here r has properties

- created_at = timestamp()
- money_transferred = amount of money transferred

How can I find one users last sent money to other user or last received money from other user in single query.

I have tried this query

```
MATCH (from:User)-[r:SENT_MONEY]->(to:User)
where (id(from)=1234 OR  id(to)=1234)
return max(r.created_at) as sent_at,
r.money_transferred as amount, from.username,to.username
order by last_amount_sent_at DESC
```

Results are like:

```
sent_at    | amount | from.username | to.username
1408961056 |  20    |   user1 | user2
1408961041 | 30     |   user2 | user1
1408961028 | 50     | user1 | user3
1408951163 | 20     | user4 |   user1
1408951140 | 10     | user1 |   user4
```

By this query user "user1" records with "user2" and "user4" comes twice. It should come single with last transaction between those users like

```
sent_at    | amount | from.username | to.username
1408961056 |  20    |   user1 | user2
1408961028 | 50     | user1 | user3
1408951163 | 20     | user4 |   user1
```

Comment: Consider using undirected edges in your MATCH.   You're asking about from -> to.   You can instead formulate this as:  MATCH (A:User)-[r:SENT_MONEY]-(B:User).   Notice the lack of the arrow head >.  Then, constrain just A's ID.  That way, A could be either the "from" node, or the "two" node, depending on the direction of the relationship, which you haven't specified.   This creates the problem though of sorting out which was from and to in the RETURN clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Satish,

Here's a query that I think will do what you need.

```
MATCH (m:User {username : 'user1'})-[r:SENT_MONEY]-(n:User)
WITH m, n, collect(r) AS rs, max(r.created_at) AS p
WITH m, n, filter(x IN rs WHERE x.created_at = p) AS l
RETURN STARTNODE(l[0]), ENDNODE(l[0]), l[0]
```

For each pair of users you collect the transactions and find the last one, then return the start and end node of that last transaction.

Grace and peace,

Jim

In answer to your further question, you can modify the query like this (for example) to avoid the collection vs element error:

```
MATCH (m:User {username : 'user1'})-[r:SENT_MONEY]-(n:User)
WITH m, n, collect(r) AS rs, max(r.created_at) AS p
WITH m, n, filter(x IN rs WHERE x.created_at = p) AS o
RETURN m, n, o[0], (o[0]).money_transferred
```

Comment: How can i access relationship's properties 

In above example if i try to access l[0].amount

Type mismatch: expected Map, Node or Relationship but was Collection<Relationship>

Comment: It doesn't work. I use extract() function and it works.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using 2.1.3, and it worked when I tested it, but whatever way works is great!